# El botón de mi extensión en chrome no añade elementos al objeto

Tags: javascript, web, extensión-google-chrome

estoy creando una extensión en Google Chrome para poder gestionar ciertos ticket.

Una de las funciones que tengo en mente es un botón que guarde la página actual (la que está en el foco) en un objeto `obj` conteniendo el título y la url de la misma.

En el `popup.js` tengo:

```
var obj = [];
function init() {
    Add();
}

function Add() {
    const boton = document.getElementById("add");
    boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs =>{
            
            let title = tabs[0].title;
            let url = tabs[0].url;
            
            obj.push({"url":url, "title":title});

            let string = JSON.stringify(obj);

            consol("Se añade un objeto con el push");
            consol("Ahora el objeto es: " + string);
        });
    })
}

init();
```

**Aclarado:** La función `consol()` la uso para poder mostrar cosas en la consola de backgraund.

Lo que me devuelve cada vez que hago click es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se sobreescriben los datos o el objeto se pasa vacío por cada click?
Lo ideal sería que me fuera añadiendo las páginas por cada click.

Posteriormente con otro botón me gustaría poder descargarme un .json con esos datos pero eso es harina de otro costal..

Gracias!!